# add_rewrite Rule

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I want to add a rewrite rule, the remove the "base" from a custom taxonomy link.

There current structure is:

http://example.com/bundesland/TERMSLUG

I would like to have it like this:

http://example.com/TERMSLUG

I tried it with this:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('bundesland/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?bl_tax=$1', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

and flushed the rewrite rules after that via Backend -> Permalinks Page.

I get no change with that function.
What is wrong, there?

This code registers the tax:

```
register_taxonomy(
        'bl_tax',
        array( 'stadt'),
        array(
            'label'                     => __( 'Bundesländer' ),
            'sort'                      => TRUE,
            'public'                    => TRUE,
            'query_var'                 => 'bl_tax',
            'hierarchical'              => TRUE,
            'rewrite'                   => array('slug' => '/bundesland'),
        )
    );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you plan on using the `page` post type at all on your site? Removing the base with just a rewrite rule will cause all top-level pages to 404, since WordPress will always be trying to look in your taxonomy to resolve those requests. that's why the base exists, to provide uniqueness to different types of content.

Comment: also please don't ask multiple questions that are essentially the same. you can edit your questions to add more info and what you've tried, which you could have done with [your other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177838/remove-rewrite-path-for-custom-taxonomy).

Comment: @Milo My other quetion ist refering to a cpt, this one to a taxonomy. So I thought it would be better, to post 2 questions. Theere must be way, to solve the problem above by a custom functio. I tried it with a plugin and it wokred, but i want to avoid, to use a plugin. I used this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-htaccess-control/.

Comment: sure it's possible, but it's much more involved than a rewrite rule. if that plugin solves your problem, then look at the code the plugin uses to achieve that result.